# Continuing Execution after Exception found

Tags: java, sql-server, exception, try-catch, sql-insert

I am making a small program to insert from a text document into a database. I used a hashmap to get the values from the text document because I do not want to use arrays and the text document is in format Key:value. At the moment my code inserts correctly but when an exception is found the program ends at the point of the exception. My goal is to make it run even after an exception is found, it won't necesarrily ignore it but I want to keep executing regardless.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                                "C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Documents\\pruebasx.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

e1.printStackTrace();
}
String line;
try {
line = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}

String query = " insert into FRONTMC.HECHO (folio_hecho, folio_orden, emisora, serie,"
                            + "clave_sentido, titulos_hecho, precio, importe, liquidacion, contraparte, id_estatus, isin, contrato,"
                            + "secondary_exec_id, exec_id, F11_ClOrdID, fecha_recepcion, fecha_sentra)"
                                + " values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120),convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120))";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;
try {
preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
} catch (SQLException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
Map<Integer,String> hm1 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i != tokens.length; i++) {
        int dataIndex = tokens[i].indexOf('=') + 1;
        String data = tokens[i].substring(dataIndex);
        hm1.put(new Integer(i),data);
        }
for(int counter =0;counter <=line.length();counter++){
    preparedStmt.setString(1, hm1.get(19));
    preparedStmt.setString(2, hm1.get(19));
    preparedStmt.setString(3, hm1.get(3));
    preparedStmt.setString(4, hm1.get(34));
    preparedStmt.setString(5, hm1.get(15));
    preparedStmt.setString(6, hm1.get(30));
    preparedStmt.setString(7, hm1.get(16));
    preparedStmt.setString(8, hm1.get(18));
    preparedStmt.setString(9, hm1.get(8));
    preparedStmt.setString(10, hm1.get(33));
    preparedStmt.setString(11, hm1.get(27));
    preparedStmt.setString(12, hm1.get(17));
    preparedStmt.setString(13, hm1.get(26));
    preparedStmt.setString(14, hm1.get(23));
    preparedStmt.setString(15, hm1.get(10));
    preparedStmt.setString(16, hm1.get(14));

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(hm1.get(6)));
    String newfecha1 = ds2;
    preparedStmt.setString(17, newfecha1);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String ds4 = sdf4.format(sdf3.parse(hm1.get(6)));
    String newfecha3 = ds4;
    preparedStmt.setString(18, newfecha3);
    }
    try{
        preparedStmt.execute();
    }catch(SQLException e3){
    e3.printStackTrace();
    reader.readLine();
    continue;
    }
    }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
    System.out.println("e1.getmessage()");
    }
```

I have tried enclosing the prepared statement in a try catch, but it still stops, I have also as you can see used a continue, but it still stops. Everything runs ok, I just want to keep it executing after errors, where is the problem? The error at the moment is the one at the bottom ParseException. I want to run after getting this exception.

Comment: You are only catching `SQLException`. Is a different exception being thrown? Also, what it the purpose of the `for(int counter...` loop? It just looks to be doing the same thing many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `try/catch` blocks into the `while`:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    try {
        String[] tokens = line.split("");
        for (int i = 0; i != tokens.length; i++) {
            int dataIndex = tokens[i].indexOf('=') + 1;
            String data = tokens[i].substring(dataIndex);
            hm1.put(new Integer(i),data);
        }
        // Try to parse line and insert into db
        preparedStmt.setString(1, hm1.get(19));
        preparedStmt.setString(2, hm1.get(19));
        // etc....
        // No other try/catch here to skip entire 
        // line on error
        preparedStmt.execute();
    }
    catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ParseException e3) {
        System.out.println("e3.getmessage()");
    }
} // while
```

Comment: Same problem, when I get an exception, the program ends. I want the program to continue. For example let's say the text document has 5 lines on the 3rd line there is an error. I want there to be 4 inserts. A the moment my program only inserts the first two lines, hits error and stops.

Comment: I have not yet tried the update version but if it helps I put the number 17 and 18 exceptions in their own try/catch and the execution of the whole text file was successful, but I wanted to skip the line and keep continuing. For example, if I have 5 text lines and on line 3 I have and error, I want to insert lines 12,4,and 5 skipping line 3. At the moment the modification made it so it inserts all 5 lines.

Comment: `try {
 ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(hm1.get(6)));
 } catch (ParseException e1) {          
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
 }`

Comment: If you want to skip the whole line, remove all `try/catch` from within the outer `try/catch`.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried but when I take one it gives me an error and makes me put in a try/catch

Comment: After a few modificiations, just took out one of your catches, it finally got working. Tanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your try block is mostly taken up by a for loop, which I assume has multiple chances to throw an exception.

Would it be possible for you to move the try-catch block inside of that for loop instead of outside? That way, you could catch multiple exceptions over the course of the loop without stopping it.

By the way, could you write which statements in your block throw the SQLException?

Comment: I modified the code a bit and the statements which throw the Exception are number 17 and 18. Keep in mind this exception is on purpose I am trying to make it break. It is an unparsable date exception. I want to continue even if it comes up.

Comment: I moved the try block for the execution of the prepared statement and it makes it run 360 times and still when it reaches the error it stops.

Comment: What do you mean by "want to continue even if it comes up". You want the code to continue setting rest of the parameters? Or you want the code to handle the exception elegantly? I am sorry the question ain't too clear to me.

Comment: I want the code to continue setting the rest of the parameters, I want it to keep inserting into the database.